# Is $f_n(x)=x/(nx+1)$ uniformly convergent in domain [0, 1]?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{nx+1}$ uniformly convergent in domain [0, 1]? If yes, how to show?

Comment: This question can't be answered unless you specify a domain for the functions $f_n$.

Comment: But once a domain has been specified, it may help to rewrite it to $f=\frac1n\cdot \frac{x}{x+1/n}$.

Comment: Domain is [0,1].